BigQuery Arima Plus forecasts are higher than expected
I am trying to predict values from a lot of different devices (1000s, testing on a few hundred for performance reasons) on 15 min resolution. All of the devices log: name and value. I have tried different time ranges for training but so far no luck.
A few examples of the issue:
A device logs 40 all the time -> Arima predicts range of 20-80 starting with 1st prediction (30d training)
A device logs 60-64 -> Arima predicts 65-120 spikes which then flatten at 102 (1d training). I am struggling to understand how Arima plus even arrived at values magnitudes higher than all values in training dataset.
This is pseudocode of the arima plus model creation and forecasting:
I am using a summary table as a source with data at 15 min resolution
training:
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL forecasting.model
  OPTIONS(
    MODEL_TYPE='ARIMA_PLUS'
    ,TIME_SERIES_TIMESTAMP_COL='timestamp'
    ,TIME_SERIES_DATA_COL='value'
    ,TIME_SERIES_ID_COL='id'
    -- ,auto_arima = TRUE
    ,clean_spikes_and_dips = FALSE
    ,adjust_step_changes = FALSE
    -- ,data_frequency = 'AUTO_FREQUENCY'
    -- ,auto_arima_max_order = 2 -- default is 5
   -- ,max_time_series_length = 96 -- 1 d?
  ) AS
      (
      SELECT timestamp
        ,id
        ,SUM(value) as value

      FROM `forecasting.summary`
      WHERE CAST(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(timestamp, DAY) AS DATE) < _CUTOFF_DATE
        AND CAST(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(timestamp, DAY) AS DATE) >= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL _PERIOD DAY)
      GROUP BY 1,2

      );

While I do use SUM(value), pretty sure its sum of only 1 row. Left from other attempts.
SELECT 
    id
    ,forecast_timestamp as timestamp
    ,forecast_value as value
    ,standard_error 
    ,confidence_level 
    ,prediction_interval_lower_bound 
    ,prediction_interval_upper_bound
  FROM 
    ML.FORECAST(MODEL `forecasting.forecast`
                  ,STRUCT(672 as horizon -- 192 is 2d; 672 is 7d 
                          ,0.95 as confidence_level
                  )
    )
    ;

One approach which worked for me in the past is to predict each 15m as its own time series. The problem is, it would lead to tens or hundreds thousands of timeseries in this case. While ArimaPlus claims to be able to handle millions, it's training performance is already slow if I do 30d and do not limit max pdq.
I had a similar issue on forecasting of data exhibiting a daily and weekly seasonality. In the current case with device data, there is likely daily and annual seasonality related to climate and weather conditions.
How can I make Arima work? If not, what approach would you recommend?

Arima plus is sensitive to outliers and sudden shifts in data. Just summing values loses crucial information about the 15-minute resolution variation. Instead of summing, probably you can consider aggregating based on meaningful time periods like daily or weekly totals/averages. This reduces the number of time series and helps smooth out the noise.
Finding the optimal approach will involve experimenting with different combinations of preprocessing, models, and hyperparameters. You can also go check and see these best practices for large-scale time series.

Hello, thank  you for your response. I need to predict on a sub daily and preferably sub hourly intervals. The goal is to detect anomalies as close to realtime as possible. Data seasonality is daily and weekly (there might be annual but I do not have year+ of data). The data does not come in regular intervals, each device is sending it every few seconds (no consistent interval).
Consider this case: The device logs 40 all the time. The 15 min average is 40 (no info loss, literally straight line). And yet if I run arima plus on it, it predicts 20-80 jagged line.
